# What is the difference between discarding DoAwait() VS Task.Run(() => DoAwait())

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

So let's assume I have the following async method:

```cs
public async Task DoAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    ExecuteContinuation();
}
```

Now I want to execute this task in a fire-and-forget way from ASP.NET (non-Core) Controller method (I know that's not the best idea, but that's not the scope of the question).
Therefore I simply discard returned task:

```cs
_ = DoAsync();
```

That leads to an interesting result - `ExecuteContinuation()` is never executed, breakpoint is never hit.
Now if I wrap it in Task.Run, everything works just fine:

```cs
_ = Task.Run(() => DoAsync());
```

Question is - why such behavior happens, and why `ExecuteContinuation()` is never executed without Task.Run?

As far as I remember, `Task.Run` forces the task to execute on a thread pool ignoring SynchronizationContext, but does it make any difference, considering that I never `await` returned task?

Another thing - `_ = DoAsync();` works as expected if I do same with ASP.NET **Core**. I suppose because there is no `SynchronizationContext`, but again - I don't know why that matters in this case.

Comment: Is `ExecuteContinuation` throwing an exception? You wouldn't know because you aren't `await`ing on the `Task` -- Fire-and-forget with `async` is a bad idea.

Comment: Nope, it is simply not executed at all. If I put a breakpoint in debug on that line, it is never hit.

Comment: As I mentioned, I know it's a bad idea, and that's not how I'm planning to leave it. Still, I'd like to understand what causes this behavior.

Comment: Try adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to `Task.Delay()`

Comment: Yep, adding ConfigureAwait(false) helps as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as I remember, Task.Run forces the task to execute on a thread pool ignoring SynchronizationContext, but does it make any difference, considering that I never await returned task?

Yes. It makes a difference for the `await` inside `DoAsync`. When calling it directly, it will capture the current `SynchronizationContext` (representing the current request). Later when that `await` resumes executing, it will attempt to resume on the captured context for the request that has already completed. The resulting behavior is undefined.

When calling `DoAsync` from `Task.Run`, no context is captured and `DoAsync` may resume executing on any thread pool thread without the context for the completed request.

Note that since this is fire-and-forget, it is inevitable that `DoAsync` will occasionally not finish, even when using `Task.Run`. Your system as a whole *must* properly handle that scenario. The [proper solution for fire-and-forget code is a distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html).

Comment: Have I been depending on a missing safety net for two years? On a synchronous (returns IActionResult rather than Task<IActionResult>) bare Controller action, I conditionally call an async void function that starts with Task.Delay(1) to move it onto the background thread. The function runs until the service is disposed, which in production is never.

Comment: Actually starts with Task.Delay(1) is an oversimplification. It sets up some control variables first, including the no-reentrancy check so I don't start two of them.

Comment: +1. Just complementing, you can use ContinueWith to handle some situation, instead directly call ExecuteContinuation(). Example: .ContinueWith((i) => { /*do something*/}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted /*choose TaskContinuationOptions that makes sense to you*/);

Comment: @Joshua: Yes; if you're on ASP.NET pre-Core and if you're not using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, then that would be dangerous - the code is capturing and resuming on a request context that is long-gone. That doesn't *necessarily* mean it will fail, but it *may*.

Comment: @AugustoFerbonink: `ContinueWith` is a much lower-level method. At the very least, you should *always* pass a `TaskScheduler` to `ContinueWith`.

Comment: Fresh observation from Net 8. I always did like this: _ = DoAsync(); but recently I met a code that always throws a weird Net-level exception exactly at the moment of such call. Some "timer synchronization" exception. Task.Run solves this, even though it's assumed in Net 8 no synchronization context, and moreover, the call is originated from background service so should be no synchronization context anyway.